# SVG area visibility depending on overlap parity

Tags: svg

In an SVG file, I need to make the areas where an even number of primitives overlap invisible. Below one works in Chrome but not in Firefox. Is there a better supported way?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <path id="first" d="M 50 50 L 150 50 L 150 150 z" fill="silver" />
    <path id="second" d="M 50 50 L 50 150 L 150 50 z" fill="silver" />
    <circle id="third" r="30" cx="100" cy="100" fill="silver" />
    <filter id="composite">
      <feImage xlink:href="#first" result="f" />
      <feImage xlink:href="#second" result="s" />
      <feComposite operator="xor" in="f" in2="s" result="fs" />
      <feImage xlink:href="#third" result="t" />
      <feComposite operator="xor" in="fs" in2="t" />
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <g filter="url(#composite)">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: In firefox feImage must point to a complete image e.g a data url or an external image. It can't point to a fragment.

Comment: Thank you! Compatibility table at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feImage#browser_compatibility points to a long living issue at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=455986 . And you're on that discussion, a nice surprise :)